# How would i check if my receiver blows speakers

Tags: home-theater, speakers, audio

I picked up a Yamaha htr-3064 from good will for $14.99. Seamed like quite the steal. Back of the unit says it can take 6 or 8ohms speakers. I had also picked up a pair of Tandy Realistic tower speakers, said 8ohms max. Looked good, mesh was intact and cones were clean. So i hooked them up to the bannana plugs and i had no sound, no crackle or pop. After the fact i opened the speakers up and 1 had noticable charing on a wire going to the cone and no continuity. I then hooked my multimeter to the outputs on the receiver and could hear the music theme from my Playstation. The volume is at -33.5 to hear the start of the beat and around -29 for vocals and other instruments. With distortion and buzzing of the multimeter of course.

If i hear music from my multimeter would that mean my reciever is fine?

What would be the proper way to test that the reciever is not the one to blame?

Comment: This will likely be closed, as small appliance repair seems to be off topic. Are you sure the speakers were functional _before_ you plugged them in, or was that wire shot when you bought it?

Answer (score 1):

Generic advice: test the speakers on a known functional system. Test the receiver with speakers known to be functional.

My suspicion is that the speakers are toast.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you connected an analogue multimeter  (the kind with a moving pointer) to the speaker terminals.. if you hear sound from the needle that's a good sign.

if the meter shows no DC voltage (juat music wiggles around zero) that's another
good sign.

repeat the tests with 8 (ish) ohm load (eg a hairdryer) in parallel with the meter.
if they pass again your receiver is probably good.